# Error using Dataproc and Spark BigQuery Connector within DataLab Notebooks

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-datalab

Am able to get Google Datalab (Notebooks) running in Google Chrome with the correct TCP firewall permissions. Using the simple script, this launches the most current spark cluster (1 master with 3 workers using Dataproc). First we test the below code in `spark-submit`, then after launching DataLab I'm not sure how to fix the below error.

**First step: Launch Dataproc Cluster from Cloud Shell**

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster1021 \
    --subnet default --zone us-west1-a \
    --master-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
    --master-boot-disk-size 30 --num-workers 2 \
    --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
    --worker-boot-disk-size 30 --image-version 1.3-deb9 \
    --project bigdata-228217 \
    --initialization-actions 'gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/datalab/datalab.sh','gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/connectors/connectors.sh' \
    --metadata 'gcs-connector-version=1.9.11' \
    --metadata 'bigquery-connector-version=0.13.11'
```

After successfully launching I tested to see that the Bigquery connector is working with `spark-submit wordcount.py` example from [Google here.](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example)

**Second step: Include this code in the master home directory as `wordcount.py` with `touch wordcount.py`, then paste in below code from `nano wordcount.py` and save.**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""BigQuery I/O PySpark example."""
from __future__ import absolute_import
import json
import pprint
import subprocess
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

# Use the Cloud Storage bucket for temporary BigQuery export data used
# by the InputFormat. This assumes the Cloud Storage connector for
# Hadoop is configured.
bucket = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.system.bucket')
project = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.project.id')
input_directory = 'gs://{}/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_input'.format(bucket)

conf = {
    # Input Parameters.
    'mapred.bq.project.id': project,
    'mapred.bq.gcs.bucket': bucket,
    'mapred.bq.temp.gcs.path': input_directory,
    'mapred.bq.input.project.id': 'publicdata',
    'mapred.bq.input.dataset.id': 'samples',
    'mapred.bq.input.table.id': 'shakespeare',
}

# Output Parameters.
output_dataset = 'wordcount_dataset'
output_table = 'wordcount_output'

# Load data in from BigQuery.
table_data = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    'com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'com.google.gson.JsonObject',
    conf=conf)

# Perform word count.
word_counts = (
    table_data
    .map(lambda record: json.loads(record[1]))
    .map(lambda x: (x['word'].lower(), int(x['word_count'])))
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y))

# Display 10 results.
pprint.pprint(word_counts.take(10))

# Stage data formatted as newline-delimited JSON in Cloud Storage.
output_directory = 'gs://{}/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_output'.format(bucket)
output_files = output_directory + '/part-*'

sql_context = SQLContext(sc)
(word_counts
 .toDF(['word', 'word_count'])
 .write.format('json').save(output_directory))

# Shell out to bq CLI to perform BigQuery import.
subprocess.check_call(
    'bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON '
    '--replace '
    '--autodetect '
    '{dataset}.{table} {files}'.format(
        dataset=output_dataset, table=output_table, files=output_files
    ).split())

# Manually clean up the staging_directories, otherwise BigQuery
# files will remain indefinitely.
input_path = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(input_directory)
input_path.getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()).delete(input_path, True)
output_path = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(output_directory)
output_path.getFileSystem(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()).delete(
    output_path, True)
```

Now, from the shell, The output from `spark-submit` here are the results -- showing that the BigQuery connector works.

```
spark-submit wordcount.py
...
(pinnace,3)
(bone,21)
(lug,2)
(vailing,2)
(bombast,3)
(gaping,11)
(hem,5)
('non,1)
(stinks,1)
(forsooth,48)
```

**Step 3 Set up Firewall to allow for TCP DataLab view in Browser**

[image]

Create firewall rule for DataLab

[image]

On the setup page, you'll create a name for the DataLab firewall rule, and allow for the below TCP ports, along with "/32" immediately after your network's IP address -- which you can find [here](https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-address-lookup/).

**Step 4: Launch DataLab in Google Chrome with `<YOUR IP>:8080` and you should see the DataLab Notebook**

[image]

You'll see this. Now open a new notebook, and in the first cell I stopped the spark context and pasted the above Shakespeare code into the second cell.

[image]

Here is the output. Question, what do I need to do to get the Bigquery Connector to work with Pyspark in Datalab??

```
Py4JJavaErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-62761a09a7c5> in <module>()
     36     'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
     37     'com.google.gson.JsonObject',
---> 38     conf=conf)
     39 
     40 # Perform word count.

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py in newAPIHadoopRDD(self, inputFormatClass, keyClass, valueClass, keyConverter, valueConverter, conf, batchSize)
    735         jrdd = self._jvm.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(self._jsc, inputFormatClass, keyClass,
    736                                                    valueClass, keyConverter, valueConverter,
--> 737                                                    jconf, batchSize)
    738         return RDD(jrdd, self)
    739 

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDDFromClassNames(PythonRDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from [this line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/24a8d028543d5dd3c8e0a336718035e22cf80633/datalab/datalab.sh#L37), Datalab init action mounts BQ and GCS connectors into Docker container.

Because Dataproc 1.3 does not come with BQ connector by default and because you specified Connectors init action, that installs BQ connector on the cluster, after DataLab init action, Docker can not mount BQ connector into Datalab container during Datalab init action execution.

To fix this issue you need to change order of init actions:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create \
    . . .
    --initialization-actions=gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/datalab/connectors.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/connectors/datalab.sh
```

As a minor improvement, you don't need to specify GCS connector version (`--metadata 'gcs-connector-version=1.9.11'`) at the moment, because latest Dataproc 1.3 image already has GCS connector 1.9.11 pre-installed.

Comment: Perfect solution; it worked! Straight from the source. Any flags for setting up the Datalab with https? Also, would be useful to have a metadata option when setting up via the Dataproc launch screen with an output of the linux gcloud output. Also, would be great to have a default install of the BQ connector from Dataproc install.

Comment: Do you mean if there are a possibility to access Datalab without [ssh tunnel](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/dataproc-datalab#open_the_datalab_name_short_notebook_in_your_browser) directly from internet? If so, no - the safest option right now is to use SSH tunnel (in this case it doesn't matter if this is HTTP or HTTPS protocol).

Comment: We decide to not pre-install BQ connector on Dataproc clusters because doing so limits our ability to evolve and modify it (if it will be pre-installed we need to be stricter about backward compatibility with older versions that already pre-installed on Dataproc clusters). Also, it could create class path conflicts when customers will include it in their job JARs/TARs